# Eigenvalues of $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am relatively new to eigenvalues & eigenvectors so I am still confuse with what to do in most parts!

Let
$$A= \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & a & b           \\[0.3em]
      a & 2 & c \\[0.3em]
      b & c & 3
     \end{bmatrix}$$
with $a \ ,b \ ,c ∈ R$. What could be eigenvalues?

A) $1 , 3 , 6$

B) $0,1,3$

C) $1,4,6$

D) $1,2,3$

**Working:**
I know to calculate
$$det(A-\lambda I) = .\begin{bmatrix}
      1- \lambda & a & b           \\[0.3em]
      a & 2-\lambda & c \\[0.3em]
      b & c & 3-\lambda
     \end{bmatrix}$$

But I get confused when calculating this with the constants! I would absolutely appreciate any help!

Comment: There exists a relation between the trace of the matrix and its eigenvalues. Does that help you?

Comment: @molarmass I'm sorry, I don't understand! what do you mean?

Comment: If $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, then $\operatorname{Trace}(A)=\lambda_1+ \lambda_2+\lambda_3$.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your confusion when calculating? What happens when you attempt to calculate the determinant of that matrix using the ordinary method of calculating determinants?

Answer (score 2):

Always remember these two fact,

i) sum of eigenvalues= trace of the matrix(sum of the diagonal)

ii) product of eigenvalues= determinant of the matrix.

In your case, $a,b,c$ are arbitrary so we can't say anything about the determinant of the matrix , but we can see that the trace of the matrix is 6. i.e. by (i) sum of the eigenvalues must be 6, which is satisfied by option(D) only.

Note:
Here, (D) gives a possible set of eigenvalues for particular values of $a,b,c$ .
For different values of $a,b,c$ we  will get different set of eigenvalues.
Out of those eigenvalues, (D) is just a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the determinant is equal to: $\operatorname{det}(A-\lambda I) = (1-\lambda)\operatorname{det}\begin{pmatrix} 2-\lambda & c\\ c & 3-\lambda \end{pmatrix} + (-1) \cdot a \cdot \operatorname{det} \begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & 3- \lambda \end{pmatrix} + \dots$

Can you finish it yourself?

Comment: In this case, though, there’s no need to compute this determinant. You can simply compare the purported eigenvalues to the trace of the matrix per molarmass’ comment above.